# Weird Error message in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a program that I am trying to make, and so far things seem to be going well. I've been busy debugging a certain chunk of code, and it works fine in the debugger. The problem, however, is that the program still crashes. When I go through the debugger window, it looks like it's something outside of my own code. The error message is:

```
Unable to disassemble dyld_stub_writev
```

That's what I see when I look at the console. I've tried to do a search on this, but I seriously got no results. Does anyone have any idea what this error message means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, solved it. Turns out I wasn't releasing an NSArray right, so I just set it up as a property in the header file, and it works now.